# Paper related to RTABMAP odometry

Tags: slam, navigation, odometry, rtabmap-odometry, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

Is there any paper related to the rtabmap_odometry node, especially presenting the various algorithms used (SURF features and RANSAC matching function according to this [paper](https://introlab.3it.usherbrooke.ca/mediawiki-introlab/images/e/eb/Labbe14-IROS.pdf)

I only found papers about the back end solutions... As well as info in the official [forum](http://official-rtab-map-forum.206.s1.nabble.com/How-does-RGBD-Slam-works-td191.html)

Thanks a lot!
Quentin

---

edit:

1. In the case of the ICP refining, is it possible to use a "known" 3D point cloud and then to use it as a "skeleton" in which the odometry is computed? ICP should align the local point cloud and this known global point cloud.
2. As I am not an expert in image processing, could you advice me the most efficient solution for odometry tracking? My system should run on a UAV - computing power limited - with airborn 2D laser scanner and kinect.

Thanks for your advice!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241665/paper-related-to-rtabmap-odometry/) by [quentin](https://answers.ros.org/users/24914/quentin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2016-08-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-08-23**:
@quentin: please don't post answers, unless you are actually *answering* your own question. For everything else, use *comments* or *edit* your original question. You can use the `edit` button/link for that (below your question). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At that time, RTAB-Map's related papers use wheel odometry instead of visual odometry. Unfortunately, there is no paper about RTAB-Map's visual odometry approaches.

- The default one is Frame-to-Map with
  OpenCV's GFTT/BRIEF features,
  correspondences by descriptors
  matching, 3D->3D PCL's RANSAC
  registration with known
  correspondences.
- Another combination I use sometime
  (with car-like motions):
  Frame-to-KeyFrame with OpenCV's GFTT
  features, correspondences by optical
  flow, 2D->3D OpenCV's
  Perspective-n-Points
  (cv::solvePnPRansac).

It is also possible to add ICP refining if you have 2D laser scans or 3D point clouds. The choice of features are SIFT, SURF, ORB, BRIEF, FREAK, FAST or BRISK. ORB and FAST are also good fast choices. GFTT is nice because it can detect uniformly distributed features across the image. SIFT/SURF are slow for odometry, but really good for loop closure detection.

Another [post](http://official-rtab-map-forum.206.s1.nabble.com/Ransac-Frame-to-Frame-Stability-td225.html) related to **Frame-to-Frame** vs **Frame-to-Map** approaches used.

**EDIT**

1. No, it is not possible.
2. You may want to look at Visual Inertial Odometry (VIO) approaches, though you would need hardware synchronized IMU/camera. In RTAB-Map, you cannot use a 2D laser scan to refine 6DoF odometry, only 3DoF (in case of a ground vehicle on flat surface).

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [quentin](https://answers.ros.org/users/24914/quentin/) on 2016-08-23**:
Thanks a lot for these answers! I edited my initial post with two additional questions @matlabbe might be able to answer!

**Comment by [h66](https://answers.ros.org/users/20672/h66/) on 2018-04-05**:
Hi @matlabbe, is there any paper now (2 years after the original post), explaining how the rgbd_odometry works?. Looking at the source code of 'OdometryROS.cpp' It seems that the map is generated and then the transformations between frames are estimated and converted to odometry?. Thanks!

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2018-04-06**:
OdometryROS is a wrapper of Odometry from rtabmap library. The two standard ones are F2M (frame-to-map) and F2F (frame-to-frame). For F2M, the map is a temporary feature map used only for odometry, it is independent from the map of rtabmap.